# XMLHttpRequest POST and Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I have a webpage with javascript that POSTs json data to a python flask app.
Everything works fine with Chrome, Edge, Opera, Android, a.s.o.
Just Firefox gives me an error.

This is my javascript:

```
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open("POST", url);
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json;charset=UTF-8");
  xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authdata);

  xhr.onreadystatechange = function(ev) {
     //2 - request sent, 3 - something back, 4 - full response
     //console.log(xhr.readyState);
     if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        switch (xhr.status) {
        case 200:
        case 304:
          console.log("OK or Not Modified (cached)", xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          break;
        case 201:
          console.log("Created", xhr.status);
          console.log(xhr.responseText);
          break;
        case 400:
          console.log("Bad Request", xhr.status);
          alert("Bad Request");
          break;
        case 401:
        case 403:
          console.log("Not Authorized or Forbidden", xhr.status);
          alert("Not Authorized or Forbidden");
          break;
        case 404:
          console.log("Not Found", xhr.status);
          alert("404 Not Found");
          break;
        case 500:
          console.log("Server Side Error", xhr.status);
          alert("Server Error 01 Code: " + xhr.status.toString());
          break;
        default:
          console.log("Some other code: ", xhr.status);
          alert("Server Error 02 Code: " + xhr.status.toString());
        }
    }
 };

 xhr.onerror = function(err) {
   console.warn(err);
   alert("Server Error 99", err);
 };

 edata = JSON.stringify({ "domain": "workdomain", "zonedata": "data" });
 xhr.send(edata);
```

When I fire this in Firefox I get a "Server Error 02" status code 0
And if I look into debugger network tab there is just no POST send.

Is this a Firefox problem?

Comment: _"Is this a Firefox problem?"_ - still using XMLHttpRequest instead of `fetch` in 2022, is probably rather what you could call a problem on the developer side :-)

Comment: not sure if it's a Firefox problem - I've never seen an Error Code 02 - oh, wait, that's your code doing that ...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/status: _"Browsers also report a status of 0 in case of XMLHttpRequest errors."_ - you got any other errors in the browser console? Is this cross-domain / affected by CORS?

Comment: is `url` http://.....? https://....? something  else?

Comment: There are no other errors. The url is http://10.10.0.43:5555/someroute. CORS is not the problem. All other browsers send post successfully.

Comment: @CBroe What is wrong with XMLHttpRequest in 2022?

Comment: Any adblocker plugin? "Enhanced Tracking Protection" is on?

Comment: No adblocker is active

Comment: _"What is wrong with XMLHttpRequest in 2022?"_ - that it is so cumbersome to use. `fetch` in combination with promises/await, usually makes for much nicer code. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Answer (score 0):

After playing around a while I found out this is a timing issue in Firefox.

I added a setTimeout to the send statement and everything runs smoothly.

Here is the code that works now:

```
     const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
     xhr.open("POST", url);
     xhr.timeout = 0;
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", authdata);
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
     xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "*/*");

     setTimeout(function() {
        xhr.send(edata);
     }, 1000);

     xhr.onerror = function(err) {
       console.warn(err);
       alert("Server Error no response", err);
     };
```